# Need to share a copy of my functioning Google Sheet file, which auto updates every 4 hours via an API source, but the copy fails to auto update

Tags: api, google-sheets, auto-update

I currently have a perfectly operational Google Sheet file which auto-updates from an online source via an API every 4 hours and I'm very happy with its current operation.
However I need to move the Sheet to a different Google Workspace account in the same organization and change its ownership.
I've discovered that, if I make a copy of the current file in the current location, then the auto-update fails to operate.
I'm consequently unable to take the next step to share the file with another user.
(Unfortunately the author of the original Google Sheet file is no longer available)
As super admin, I could rename the user and email address, however I'm reluctant to take the risk that this might prevent the original file from functioning.
Any helpful comments most welcome.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience, copies of container bound scripts need to be authorized before they start any execution.

Try this:

1. Make a copy of the file
2. Add the other GW account as the owner of the file
3. Open the file with the new GW account and go to the Script and execute it so authorization is granted.
4. It should start updating as expected under the new owner account.

After my last test, this worked just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your very prompt and helpful answer.
Unfortunately the file contains 4 separate reference sheets and 3 script files, all of which have URL references to the original file location.
This means editing each reference to correspond with the file's new URL location, which is tedious but easy enough.
However even then the problems don't appear to be resolved as there are errors when trying to run the scripts manually reporting that I don't have required permissions to run the script, despite being the owner.

Comment: Also, when running in auto mode, the scheduled update routines using the API don't trigger so the data remains static.
Lost count of the number of attempts to correct the issue but now going try renaming the current operational Google account user and email address and fingers crossed hope this wont affect the running of the scripts.

Comment: It worked ! :) 
Renaming the desired new host account to a temporary name and renaming the old sheet host account to the desired new host account allowed the scripts to continue functioning. So now I just need to move all the other stuff from the temporary account into the renamed account and recreate all the folders, filters, forwarding rules etc. which is a drag but nevertheless the main thing is that it works :)